# better way to include anchor in ListItem and adjust item's symbol font in itextSharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iTextSharp 5.4.4, and i am trying to construct an ordered list of anchors. I am facing 2 problems:

1. if i pass the anchor directly to the constructor of the ListItem, it gets treated as a Chunk in the rendered output and loses its anchor features.
   workaround: I initialize the ListItem using the empty constructor and then I use ListItem.Add to add the anchor.

2.using the workaround above, I try to adjust the font of the list symbol to make match that of the item using

```
ListItem.AdjustListSymbolFont();
```

that does not work -i guess it's because to itext, there's no Chunk in the list item to retrieve the font from. So what i did is the following

```
var listItem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem(clickAnchor); // clickAnchor is treated as a Chunk
listItem.Add(clickAnchor); // i add the anchor again
listItem.AdjustListSymbolFont();
listItem.Remove(listItem.Chunks[0]); // after the font is adjusted, i remove the first Chunk
```

so basically i fed it an element that i know it'll treat as a Chunk so that it has one to retrieve the font from then i add that same element to the ListeItem and adjust the font.
I then remove the first Chunk, which it processed and added from the element in the first line of code. This is a very ugly workaound, but it is the only one that worked.

Are there better ways to do the above?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `clickAnchor` is an object of type `Anchor`. If you pass this to the `ListItem` as a parameter, it will be treated as a `Phrase` and all interactivity will be lost.

To avoid this, you shouldn't create an `Anchor`. Instead you should use a `Chunk` and make it interactive using the `SetAnchor()` method. This way, the anchor is preserved when you use it in a `ListItem`.

**Update:** Copy/past from the code snippet from kfc's comment:

```
var clickAnchor = new Chunk(pub.Title, anchorFont);
clickAnchor.SetLocalGoTo(i.ToString());
var listItem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem(clickAnchor);
listItem.AdjustListSymbolFont();
```

Comment: that was exactly my concern!
here's what i tried
    var clickAnchor = new Chunk(pub.Title, anchorFont);
    var listItem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem(clickAnchor);
    listItem.AdjustListSymbolFont();
    clickAnchor.SetLocalGoTo(i.ToString());
and it worked. thanks

Comment: OK, I added your code snippet to my answer for further reference. Feel free to accept the answer.